# ruby for loop using range class instead of fixnum?

Tags: ruby, range

```
for i in [0..4] do
  puts i + 1
end
```

undefined method `+' for 0..4:Range (NoMethodError)

Why is it not treating each number in the range as a fixnum within the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write instead:

```
for i in 0..4 do
```

Otherwise you don't have a range, you have an array containing 1 range.

Answer (score 2):

`[0..4]` is actually array with one range element, the same as `[(0..4)]`. You need to change it to `(0..4)`.

Comment: This answer was given earlier, by @kyflare.

Comment: Sorry I just saw this one first sinc it was voted up. I have marked first one as answer

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achive a goal:

```
0.upto(4) { |i|
  puts i
}

0.step(4, 1) { |i|
  puts i
}

5.times { |i| # 5 for inclusive
  puts i
}

for i in 0..4
  puts i
end
```

Everything will output:

```
# ⇒ 0
# ⇒ 1
# ⇒ 2
# ⇒ 3
# ⇒ 4
```

Hope it helps.